# How to trigger an event on a select menu item with JQuery

Tags: jquery, select-menu

A very basic question, I'm sure, that I can't seem to crack. What I would like to do is simply trigger a simple event when a specific option in a select menu is picked.

This is the basic SELECT menu item:

```
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value=1>1 - Does not show</option>
  <option value=2>2 - Does not show</option>
  <option value=3>3 - Does show</option>
</select>
```

The item to be targeted by the event:

```
<div id="see-me-now" style="display:none;">Boo!</div>
```

The JQuery I've got so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#mySelect").change(function(){
        $("#see-me-now").fadeIn('slow');
   });
});
```

Now, I know where I'm missing some code, I just can't seem to get exactly what that code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#mySelect").change(function(){
      $(*MISSING CODE GOES HERE, I BET*){
        $("#see-me-now").fadeIn('slow');
      });
   });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: What you have done is completely right. But you forgot to add the condition.

Comment: Do you want to *ONLY* show the div when "3" is selected?

Answer (score 1):

What you have done is completely right. But you forgot to **add the condition**. See the code below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#mySelect").change(function(){
      if ($(this).val() == 3) {
        $("#see-me-now").fadeIn('slow');
      }
   });
});
```

And also there's an error in your code. The `if` condition should have a different closing.

**Snippet**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#mySelect").change(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == 3) {
      $("#see-me-now").fadeIn('slow');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value=1>1 - Does not show</option>
  <option value=2>2 - Does not show</option>
  <option value=3>3 - Does show</option>
</select>

<div id="see-me-now" style="display:none;">Boo!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you want this?

```
if($(this).val() == 3) {
    $("#see-me-now").fadeIn('slow');
}
```

Comment: Nopes. Not mad. Sorry. Was sleeping. Removed the downvote. Sorry again. Don't get offended please.

Comment: not offended, nice to see ppl being honest here. upvote:-)